# CI automation / Jenkins - don't trigger the build if a pull request has a label assigned (or other condition)

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

In my current company we use Jenkins, previously I used TeamCity but the approach looks exactly the same.

Every time someone creates a pull request and pushes changes, CI tool (Jenkins in this case) triggers the build.

Is it possible to configure it the way that **it will trigger the build only** if a corresponding pull request has… let's say a particular label assigned or something?

In a nutshell… current build takes approx. 3 hrs. Before the PR is merged, a lot of new pushes can come and Jenkins doesn't have to run on every change because "*work is still in progress*". In Github I can add a label to PR that indicates a certain state. Can Jenkins react on that label - in this case - be idle if a *"WIP"* label is assigned to PR?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the plugin (https://github.com/anyTV/jenkins-github-skip-pr-by-title-plugin) that allows you to skip the build if PR title has `[wip],[ci skip], [skip ci]`.
The only problem here is you need to build by yourself from source.

Answer (score -1):

Seems it's not yet supported by GitHub

https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/261